# Returning 401 response in OpenID Connect server with ASOS

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I followed tutorial on [Creating your own OpenID Connect server with ASOS](https://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-introduction/). Everything works fine but in case user enters wrong credentials he will see 400 response status code. I would like to change this status code to 401. Here is code of my version of HandleTokenRequest function:

```cs
public override Task HandleTokenRequest(HandleTokenRequestContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
    {
        return GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
    }
        return base.HandleTokenRequest(context);
}

private async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(HandleTokenRequestContext context)
{
    var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserService>();

    var user = await userService.AuthenticateAsync(context.Request.Username, context.Request.Password);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var identity = CreatePrincipal(Mapper.Map<UserModel>(user), null);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties(), context.Scheme.Name);
        ticket.SetScopes(Consts.Scopes.Api1, Consts.Scopes.ApiOfflineAccess);

        context.Validate(ticket);
        return;
    }
    context.Reject(error: "invalid_grant", description: "The user name or password is incorrect.");
}
```

I do not see how to pass response code here. Is it possible in this approach?

Comment: Why do you want to return a 401? From what I've seen, a 400 is pretty standard with those errors.

Comment: Seems to be in the spec: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenErrorResponse

Comment: I was aked to change that but after reading your comment I think I should not. Thanks @juunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment an answer. 
From my experience, a 400 status code is very typical.

And it's also in the specification: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenErrorResponse

> If the Token Request is invalid or unauthorized, the Authorization
>   Server constructs the error response. The parameters of the Token
>   Error Response are defined as in Section 5.2 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749].
>   The HTTP response body uses the application/json media type with HTTP
>   response code of 400.